# Validate uploaded files by width and height in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, image, validation, upload

This code is working well. It restricts the type and size of the image before upload but in addition, I would like to restrict the maximum dimension width and height of the image before upload. I would like to restrict the upload if the width and height are not correct like the script below did for extension and size. Thank you!

```js
document.getElementById("files").addEventListener("change", validateFile)

function validateFile(){
  const allowedExtensions =  ['jpg'],
        sizeLimit = 150000; 
        

  const { name:fileName, size:fileSize } = this.files[0];

  const fileExtension = fileName.split(".").pop();
  

  if(!allowedExtensions.includes(fileExtension)){
    alert("This is not a valid image");
    this.value = null;
  }else if(fileSize > sizeLimit){
    alert("This is not a valid image")
    this.value = null;
  }
}
```

```html
    <input onchange="validateFile()" type="file" id="files" class="box_file">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [clientWidth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientWidth) & [clientHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientHeight) property for width and height and then apply your desired condition.

```js
var img = document.getElementById('files');
img.addEventListener('change', function() {
    const allowedExtensions =  ['jpg'],
        sizeLimit = 150000;     

  const { name:fileName, size:fileSize } = this.files[0];

  const fileExtension = fileName.split(".").pop();
  
  // getting height & width
  var width = img.clientWidth;
  var height = img.clientHeight;
  
  let alrt = "";

  if(!allowedExtensions.includes(fileExtension)){
    alrt += "This is not a valid image! \n";
  }
  debugger;
  if(fileSize > sizeLimit){
    alrt += "This is not a valid image! \n";
  }
  
  if(width != 200 && height != 20 ){ //checking height & width
        alrt += "not a valid dimention! \n";
    }
    
    if(alrt){
     alert(alrt);
     img.value = null;
     return false;
    }
    else{
        alert("upload successful!");
        return true;
    }

});
```

```html
<input type="file" id="files" class="box_file">
```

Comment: Thank you! But can you provide a complete working answer with my code above + yours?

Comment: @Michael777 check the updated code, your code was giving me error that's why I have changed it a bit

Comment: Thank you for your efforts. Unfortunately, I tried and nothing happened when I upload above the size limit there is no console logs and the upload is authorized.

Comment: @Michael777 I have updated the code a bit, try this now and tell me if it works or giving error

Comment: Thank you again for helping me. I will try now and I will let you know :)

Comment: Sorry..still not work..

Comment: @Michael777 what it's showing? Can you check the console, if there is any error?

Comment: No new error just not working. If you run your code snippet you will see also that there is no alert for the size.

Comment: @Michael777 my apology, try now. previously it was validating step by step, now it will validate altogether, if you don't understand anything, ask me any time, no problem at all

Comment: Wonderful!!!! Congratulations!!!! It works like a charm !!!Thank you. Thank you Thank you! +1

Comment: @Michael777 No problem! Happy to help any time. ^_^